# JGit: Is there a thread safe way to add and update files

Tags: multithreading, git, jgit

The easy way to add or update files in JGit is like this:

```
  git.add().addFilepattern(file).call()
```

But that assumes that the file exists in the Git working directory.
If I have a multi-threaded setup (using Scala and Akka), is there a way to work only on a bare repository, writing the data directly to JGit, avoiding having to first write the file in the working directory?

For getting the file, that seems to work with:

```
  git.getRepository().open(objId).getBytes()
```

Is there something similar for adding or updating files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Add" is a high-level abstraction that places a file in the index.  In a bare repository, you lack an index, so this is not a 1:1 correspondence between the functionality.  Instead, you can create a file in a new commit.  To do this, you would use an [`ObjectInserter`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/ObjectInserter.html) to add objects to the repository (one per thread, please).  Then you would:

1. Add the contents of the file to the repository, as a blob, by inserting its bytes (or providing an `InputStream`).
2. Create a tree that includes the new file, by using a [`TreeFormatter`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/TreeFormatter.html).
3. Create a commit that points to the tree, by using a [`CommitBuilder`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/CommitBuilder.html).

For example, to create a new commit (with no parents) that contains *only* your file:

```
ObjectInserter repoInserter = repository.newObjectInserter();
ObjectId blobId;

try
{
    // Add a blob to the repository
    ObjectId blobId = repoInserter.insert(OBJ_BLOB, "Hello World!\n".getBytes());

    // Create a tree that contains the blob as file "hello.txt"
    TreeFormatter treeFormatter = new TreeFormatter();
    treeFormatter.append("hello.txt", FileMode.TYPE_FILE, blobId);
    ObjectId treeId = treeFormatter.insertTo(repoInserter);

    // Create a commit that contains this tree
    CommitBuilder commit = new CommitBuilder();
    PersonIdent ident = new PersonIdent("Me", "me@example.com");
    commit.setCommitter(ident);
    commit.setAuthor(ident);
    commit.setMessage("This is a new commit!");
    commit.setTreeId(treeId);

    ObjectId commitId = repositoryInserter.insert(commit);

    repoInserter.flush();
}
finally
{
    repoInserter.release();
}
```

Now you can `git checkout` the commit id returned as `commitId`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I tried using the code (with minor changes) to add 2 files, but when I try to clone the repository afterwards using the command line, it appears to be empty. Is there something special about the way the repository has to be initialized? Does it need to have a master branch or something?

Comment: It needs a HEAD that points (eventually) to this commit.  The typical mechanism would be `HEAD` -> `refs/heads/master` -> this commit ID.

Comment: Any tips on how to create the repository using JGit so that it works with the above code? Thanks!

Comment: Check out `RefUpdate` - http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/RefUpdate.html - it's hard to write too much in these comments, so if you have questions using this API another question may be in order.